# Web Site Design Allowing XML Upload with Supporting XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, standards

We are designing a web-site allowing business to upload data via XML.  We have the XSD for the XML upload.  What's the industry standard in supplying the XSD for the users?  Is it provided on the web-site as a download?

Thanks--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply link to it off of the upload page and probably on a more detailed how to page.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a documentation section of your site for the developers who are creating this XML, link to it from there. Also have a link in your upload site to the section in your documentation explaining the file, and the XSD.